# Open the pdf file automatically after saving it

Tags: ios, swift

My app creates a pdf file when I hit enter button. I do this by the code below. At the moment I want to open the saved file automatically after saving.

The code for saving:

```
    @IBAction func EnterButtonAction(_ sender: AnyObject) {

    let html = "PDF FILE TITLE"

    let fmt = UIMarkupTextPrintFormatter(markupText: html)

    // 2. Assign print formatter to UIPrintPageRenderer
    let render = UIPrintPageRenderer()
    render.addPrintFormatter(fmt, startingAtPageAt: 0)

    // 3. Assign paperRect and printableRect
    let page = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 595.2, height: 1000) // A4, 72 dpi
    let printable = page.insetBy(dx: 0, dy: 0)

    render.setValue(NSValue(cgRect: page), forKey: "paperRect")
    render.setValue(NSValue(cgRect: printable), forKey: "printableRect")

    // 4. Create PDF context and draw
    let pdfData = NSMutableData()
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(pdfData, CGRect.zero, nil)

    for i in 1...render.numberOfPages {

        UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage();
        let bounds = UIGraphicsGetPDFContextBounds()
        render.drawPage(at: i - 1, in: bounds)
    }

    UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();

    // Save PDF file
    let path = "\(NSTemporaryDirectory())MyAppFile.pdf"
    pdfData.write(toFile: path, atomically: true)
    print("open \(path)") // command to open the generated file
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can open your `PDF` file using `UIDocumentInteractionController` and find the below code:

```
func showFileWithPath(path: String){
    let isFileFound:Bool? = NSFileManager.defaultManager().fileExistsAtPath(path)
    if isFileFound == true{
        let viewer = UIDocumentInteractionController(URL: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path))
        viewer.delegate = self
        viewer.presentPreviewAnimated(true)
    }
}
```

Comment: This question is not exactly about how to open a file.

Comment: @ElTomato Question : "At the moment I want to open the saved file automatically after saving."

Comment: @ElTomato Anything else I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

`pdfData.write(toFile: path, atomically: true);`  is synchronous call, so you can write code to open file directly after this line, but first check if file is written successfully .

```
var success =  pdfData.write(toFile: path, atomically: true);

if success {
 //Write code to open file in Webview or UIDocumentInteractionController
}
```